# Different Joinpoint/Segmented regression results and Durbin-Watson test

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, trend, segmented-regression, durbin-watson-test

I used the Joinpoint trend software (https://surveillance.cancer.gov/joinpoint/) and found interesting results to my data that really intrigued me.

I have mortality rates from 2001 to 2021 as follows:

| Year | Population | Deaths | Crude_Death_Rate_100k |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 172402407 | 86228 | 50.02 |
| 2002 | 174652142 | 87190 | 49.92 |
| 2003 | 176890584 | 88838 | 50.22 |
| 2004 | 181586609 | 90758 | 49.98 |
| 2005 | 184948540 | 89878 | 48.60 |
| 2006 | 187018382 | 96471 | 51.58 |
| 2007 | 188994445 | 96705 | 51.17 |
| 2008 | 190965853 | 98871 | 51.77 |
| 2009 | 192935881 | 99139 | 51.38 |
| 2010 | 194845069 | 99647 | 51.14 |
| 2011 | 196557572 | 100648 | 51.21 |
| 2012 | 198268222 | 100103 | 50.49 |
| 2013 | 199956927 | 99954 | 49.99 |
| 2014 | 201669726 | 99190 | 49.18 |
| 2015 | 203427301 | 100436 | 49.37 |
| 2016 | 205107655 | 102886 | 50.16 |
| 2017 | 206755270 | 101132 | 48.91 |
| 2018 | 208444882 | 99835 | 47.90 |
| 2019 | 210096571 | 101000 | 48.07 |
| 2020 | 211704612 | 98749 | 46.64 |
| 2021 | 213266044 | 102980 | 48.29 |

From the Joinpoint Regression Software I got the standar errors estimated from the data, so:

test 1) applying it using the uncorrelated errors option, I got 1 joinpoint as the best model (with 1 significative trend).

test 2) After this, I tested using the first order autocorrelation estimated from the data and got a negative autocorrelation parameter and 1 joinpoint as the best model (with 2 significative trends).

test 3) Finally, I tested the series above by the Durbin-Watson test using the car::durbinWatsonTest() function which resulted:

| lag | Autocorrelation | D-W Statistic | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5390758 | 0.8688534 | 0.002 |

In other words, positive autocorrelation of ~0.54. After applying to the Joinpoint software, I got a best model of 0 joinpoints and no significance at all (please, see the uploaded image to better understand). [image]

My doubt is which model should I use for this time series? Which one of these approaches is correct?

Thanks in advance.